# If......else in woocommerce function.php

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce

I'm using this function below to controll which kind of thumbnail is used at the frontend from my shop

The problem happens when I try to include this part:

```
else {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }
```

after each other of the "if's" that are on the function. I have already tried using elseif, but also returns an error.

How can I accomplish it ? Is there any mispelled sign?

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-floresta' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    } else {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }   if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-aroma' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    }   if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-revelacao' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    }  }
```

Comment: What is the error that it's returning?

Answer (score 0):

You else needs to be last in the if-elseif-else statements:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-floresta' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    }
    elseif ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-aroma' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    }   
    elseif ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'linha-revelacao' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'woocommerce_catalog' );
    }  
    else {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
}
```